# reference in the text with greek letters

Tags: citing, babel

My problem is that the citations in the text appear with greek letters instead of english. In the references at the end they appear in english (as I want). Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{MSc.bib}

\begin{document}

\par{Η διάδοση του φωτός στα αποκαταστατικά υλικά όπως στην πορσελάνη και στις σύνθετες ρητίνες έχει ερευνηθεί εκτενώς στην βιβλιογραφία \parencite{Campell} και έχει βρεθεί πως η μετάδοση του φωτός εντός αυτών των υλικών επηρεάζει την εμφάνισή τους \parencite{Arikawa}. Οι συγκεκριμένες έρευνες στις σύνθετες ρητίνες έχουν δείξει πως τόσο η διαφορετική αναλογία σε ανόργανες ενισχυτικές ουσίες όσο και το μέγεθος τους και το σχήμα τους επηρεάζει την εμφάνιση των συνθέτων ρητινών μέσω των δεικτών διάθλασης \parencite{Lim}. Οι \selectlanguage{english}{Watts}\selectlanguage{greek} και συν. ($1994$) υποστηρίζουν πως το πιο σημαντικό ρόλο στην εμφάνιση των συνθέτων ρητινών, μέσω της διάδοσης του φωτός παίζουν οι ανόργανες ενισχυτικές ουσίες ενώ η αύξηση του μεγέθους τους έχει ως αποτέλεσμα τη μείωση της διασποράς του φωτός και την μη αισθητική εμφάνιση του υλικού \parencite{Watts}. Συγκεκριμένα υπάρχει μικρότερη διασπορά του φωτός στις μικρόκοκκες σύνθετες ρητίνες και μεγαλύτερου βαθμού αδιαφάνεια σε σχέση με τις μακρόκοκκες \parencite{Powers}.}

\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}

\printbibliography[title=\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.


%% Created for Petros Mourouzis at 2018-03-16 16:04:47 +0200 


%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 



@article{Lim,
    Author = {Lim },
    Date-Added = {2018-03-13 05:12:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-03-16 13:58:37 +0000},
    Journal = {Dental Materials},
    Pages = {67-73},
    Title = {Influence of filler distribution on the color parameters of experimental resin composites.},
    Volume = {24},
    Year = {2008}}


@article{Arikawa,
    Author = {Arikawa},
    Date-Added = {2018-03-13 05:11:35 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-03-16 13:59:06 +0000},
    Journal = {Dental Materials},
    Pages = {405-11},
    Title = {Light transmittance characteristics of light-cured composite resins.},
    Volume = {14},
    Year = {1998}}

@article{Campell,
    Author = {Campbell },
    Date-Added = {2018-03-13 05:09:41 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-03-16 13:58:57 +0000},
    Journal = {J Dent Res},
    Pages = {892-4},
    Title = {Light scattering and gloss of an experimental quartz-filled composite},
    Volume = {65},
    Year = {1986}}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the bib file as well, BTW `\par` does not take any arguments

Comment: `\par` is not needed at all as it is the same as the blank line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xpacth` to prepend a `selectlanguage` instruction to the `cite` and `textcite` bibmacros:

```
\xpretobibmacro{cite}{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{textcite}{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
```

That should be enough to deal with many of the most common citation commands, but it will not work for `\fullcite`, `\citetitle`, `\citeauthor` and the likes.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretobibmacro{cite}{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{textcite}{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}

\addbibresource{MSc.bib}

\begin{document}

Η διάδοση του φωτός στα αποκαταστατικά υλικά όπως στην πορσελάνη και στις σύνθετες ρητίνες έχει ερευνηθεί εκτενώς στην βιβλιογραφία \parencite{Campell} και έχει βρεθεί πως η μετάδοση του φωτός εντός αυτών των υλικών επηρεάζει την εμφάνισή τους \parencite{Arikawa}. Οι συγκεκριμένες έρευνες στις σύνθετες ρητίνες έχουν δείξει πως τόσο η διαφορετική αναλογία σε ανόργανες ενισχυτικές ουσίες όσο και το μέγεθος τους και το σχήμα τους επηρεάζει την εμφάνιση των συνθέτων ρητινών μέσω των δεικτών διάθλασης \parencite{Lim}. Οι \selectlanguage{english}Watts\selectlanguage{greek} και συν. ($1994$) υποστηρίζουν πως το πιο σημαντικό ρόλο στην εμφάνιση των συνθέτων ρητινών, μέσω της διάδοσης του φωτός παίζουν οι ανόργανες ενισχυτικές ουσίες ενώ η αύξηση του μεγέθους τους έχει ως αποτέλεσμα τη μείωση της διασποράς του φωτός και την μη αισθητική εμφάνιση του υλικού \parencite{Campell}. Συγκεκριμένα υπάρχει μικρότερη διασπορά του φωτός στις μικρόκοκκες σύνθετες ρητίνες και μεγαλύτερου βαθμού αδιαφάνεια σε σχέση με τις μακρόκοκκες \parencite{Arikawa}.
\textcite{Campell}
\footcite{Arikawa}
\autocite{Lim}
\smartcite{Lim}
\fullcite{Campell}
\citetitle{Arikawa}
\citeauthor{Campell}

\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}

\printbibliography[title=\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I haven't checked, but depending on your use of the citation commands, you might also have to do the same with `textcite`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you switch to an English bibliography anyway, you can simply use the `language` option together with `autolang=other`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, language=english, autolang=other]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Η διάδοση του φωτός στα αποκαταστατικά υλικά όπως στην πορσελάνη και στις σύνθετες ρητίνες έχει ερευνηθεί εκτενώς στην βιβλιογραφία \parencite{sigfridsson} και έχει βρεθεί πως η μετάδοση του φωτός εντός αυτών των υλικών επηρεάζει την εμφάνισή τους \parencite{worman}. Οι συγκεκριμένες έρευνες στις σύνθετες ρητίνες έχουν δείξει πως τόσο η διαφορετική αναλογία σε ανόργανες ενισχυτικές ουσίες όσο και το μέγεθος τους και το σχήμα τους επηρεάζει την εμφάνιση των συνθέτων ρητινών μέσω των δεικτών διάθλασης \parencite{geer}. Οι \selectlanguage{english}Watts\selectlanguage{greek} και συν. ($1994$) υποστηρίζουν πως το πιο σημαντικό ρόλο στην εμφάνιση των συνθέτων ρητινών, μέσω της διάδοσης του φωτός παίζουν οι ανόργανες ενισχυτικές ουσίες ενώ η αύξηση του μεγέθους τους έχει ως αποτέλεσμα τη μείωση της διασποράς του φωτός και την μη αισθητική εμφάνιση του υλικού \parencite{sigfridsson}. Συγκεκριμένα υπάρχει μικρότερη διασπορά του φωτός στις μικρόκοκκες σύνθετες ρητίνες και μεγαλύτερου βαθμού αδιαφάνεια σε σχέση με τις μακρόκοκκες \parencite{worman}.
\textcite{sigfridsson}
\footcite{worman}
\autocite{geer}
\smartcite{geer}
\fullcite{sigfridsson}
\citetitle{worman}
\citeauthor{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's better advice. I hadn't seen it.